# How to pass variable to hook in React?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, firebase-storage

I am trying to pass some custom metadata to my firebase firestore, I believe I must pass the metadata I grabbed in my component up to the hook but am unsure how to do so,

my component:

```
const UploadForm = () => {

    const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [metadata, setMetadata] = useState(null);

    const types = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg'];

    const changeHandler = (e) => {
        let selected = e.target.files[0];
        
        if (selected && types.includes(selected.type)) {
            setFile(selected);
            setError('');
            const pieceName = document.getElementById("pieceName").value;
            const pieceDescription = document.getElementById("pieceDescription").value;
            const newMetadata = {
                customMetaData: {
                artName: pieceName,
                artDescription: pieceDescription
                }
            };
            setMetadata(newMetadata);
...
export default UploadForm;
```

& my hook:

```
const useStorage = (file, metadata) => {
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [url, setUrl] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // references
        const storageRef = projectStorage.ref(file.name);
        const collectionRef = projectFirestore.collection('images');
        storageRef.put(file).on('state_changed', (snap) => {
            let percentage = (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100;
            setProgress(percentage);
        }, (err) => {
            setError(err);
        }, async () => {
            const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
            const createdAt = timestamp();
            collectionRef.add({ url, createdAt, metadata });
            setUrl(url);
        });
    }, [file, metadata]);
    return { progress, url, error };
}

export default useStorage;
```

I am able to upload to Firebase Storage/firestore no problem but don't know how to feed this extra metadata.

Answer (score 0):

To change the metada just call the `updateMetadata` on the `ref`:

```js
const useStorage = (file, metadata) => {
    const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [url, setUrl] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        // references
        const storageRef = projectStorage.ref(file.name);
        const collectionRef = projectFirestore.collection('images');
        storageRef.put(file).on('state_changed', (snap) => {
            let percentage = (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100;
            setProgress(percentage);
        }, (err) => {
            setError(err);
        }, async () => {
            await storageRef.updateMetadata(metadata)
            const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
            const createdAt = timestamp();
            collectionRef.add({ url, createdAt, metadata });
            setUrl(url);
        });
    }, [file, metadata]);
    return { progress, url, error };
}

export default useStorage;
```

You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/file-metadata#update_file_metadata).

Comment: It does not work, when I add this await... in async the hook does not upload the image or the metadata, I have reviewed the docs unfortunately I must be missing something. Do I have to somehow explicitly call the metadata from the component somehow?

Comment: Do you get any error message? Also do you send any metadata to the hook?